# Inline-block element extends to 100% width when wrapping lines

Tags: html, css

I want to have a background color on an inline-block element that doesn't go past the widest point of text. It works fine as long as the line break in the text is explicit by adding a `<br>` tag. If there's no `<br>` tag and it wraps on its own, it goes to 100% width.

Here it is with the `<br>` tag after "ipsum".

[image]

And here it is when it wraps on its own:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/340v3hnj/

How can I have the background be the size of the text box without having to manually add `<br>` tags?

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 50px arial;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i've updated my answer to get more exact width, and you can modify the number

Comment: that question has been asked often, but there is no working answer. all the answers below use a fixed width or margin setting, but are not dynamic to the text...

Comment: This is happening because of the size of your text. The background is behind the rendered text. You can test this by making your text smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this works.

- trying inline attributes inside `<p>` tag will produce broken background effect line-by-line for the paragraph
- Since you have mentioned that width cannot be kept fixed, so margins from the container edges have been handled

Hope this works for you!

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 50px arial;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  /* try adding the following line to your code */
  margin: 0 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` and `left` and `right` padding to wrapper element. That should work.

Checkout jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/340v3hnj/15/

Answer (score 0):

use this style for your paragraph

```
p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 50px arial;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  width : 100%;
}
```

problem is with width of your paragraph i think.

Comment: this solution is better than others with fixed pixel widths

Comment: I don't think the question was understood completely. I don't want the paragraph 100%, I want it to be the width of the text.

Answer (score 0):

use something like

```css
        .wrapper {
          border: 1px solid red;
          text-align: center;
          width: 450px ;
          font:50px Arial;
        }
        .box{background:#000;padding:0px;           
         display:inline-block;
         width:300px; 
         font: 50px arial;  
         background-size:cover; 
         margin:0 auto;  
         height:100%;
         color: white;
          }
```

```html
    
    
    
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box">
    
    
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet</p>
        </div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not specify before, but using fixed pixel widths will not work. The text comes from a CMS, so I will not know the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

update the `<p></p>` style to the following and retry the code

```
p {

  position: relative;
  width:310px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 50px arial;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not specify before, but using fixed pixel widths will not work. The text comes from a CMS, so I will not know the size of the text.

Comment: changing the display to `display:inline` instead of `inline-block` can change the width to what you want , but it have other side effects

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reproduce this without forcing going to the new line, you should use margin **or** max-width to make that work.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 50px arial;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
.with-margin{
  margin: 0 66px;
}
.with-max-width{
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
Margin:
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="with-margin">Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet</p>
</div>
<br><br>
Max-width:
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="with-max-width">Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet</p>
</div>
```